# How to show $X_{t}$ is a solution to a stochastic differential equation?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

> Prove that $$X_{t} = X_{0}\cdot \text{exp}((\alpha - \beta^2/2)t +
>  \beta W_{t}) $$ is a solution to the equation $\dot{X_{t}} = \alpha
>  X_{t} + \beta X_{t} \dot{W_{t}}.$ Moreover, calculate
>   $\mathbb{E}[X_{t}]$ if $X_{0} = x$.

I haven't been able to solve this problem. I thought that the best way to go about it would be to just differentiate $X_{t}$ (with Ito differentiation) and plug it into the equation we have. But, I've been having trouble doing so. I've read several sources on Ito differentiation, and I still haven't been able to solve this problem.

I would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take logs of both sides to get
$$
\log X_{t}-\log X_{0}=\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\beta^{2}\right)t+\beta W_{t}.
$$
Note that the RHS of the above can be written as sum of integrals:
$$
\log X_{t}-\log X_{0}=\int_{0}^{t}\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\beta^{2}\right)ds+\int_{0}^{t}\beta dW_{s}.
$$
Equivalently, in differential form,
$$
dY_{t}=\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\beta^{2}\right)dt+\beta dW_{t}
\qquad
\text{where}
\qquad
Y_t \equiv \log X_t.
$$
Note, in particular, that $Y$ satisfies an Ito drift-diffusion and hence we are in a position to apply Ito's lemma to $t \mapsto f(Y_{t})\equiv\exp Y_{t}$ to get
$$
d(\exp Y_{t})=\exp Y_{t}dY_{t}+\frac{1}{2}\exp Y_{t}d[Y,Y]_{t}.
$$
Now, substitute $Y_{t}=\log X_{t}$, the equation for $dY_{t}$, and $d[Y,Y]_{t}=\beta^{2}dt$ into the above and simplify to get the desired result.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much! What is $d[Y, Y]_{t}$ here?

Comment: $[Y, Y]$ is the quadratic variation of $Y$. Sometimes $d[Y, Y]$ is written as $(dY)^2$. You might more familiar with the second notation.

Comment: @redblacktrees: the quadratic variation of an Ito drift-diffusion $dY_t = a dt + b dW_t$ is $d[Y, Y]_t = b^2 dt$. This might help you understand how we got $\beta^2 dt$ in the above.

Comment: Okay I understand

Comment: Hi, your explanation really helped me in this post. Do you mind checking out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183346/how-to-show-mathopdx-t-alpha-x-t-mathopdt-beta-mathopdw-t to see if you could clarify that one as well?